# compiling in amd64 mode (visual studio 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, x86-64

guys I want to compile a native 64 bit application. I did configure VS the right way and it works but obvisouly it is cross compiling and not compiling in native amd64 mode as my program still freezes if I try to allocate a vector with more than 1 000 000 000.

Now, my question is where I do have to put that extra "amd64" (as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s%28VS.80%29.aspx). 
I tried it under property pages > debugging > command arguments but that didn't help.

Oh, and dont be to harsh to me, I am kinda new to this topic.

Thanks in advance.

(Visual studio  2010 ultimate edition on windows 7 professional.)

EDIT: to Bo

I don't know as I am running it in release mode and I do actually get "...exe has stopped working" message. In addition I am adding elements with push back and it works for 1 000 000 000 elements but not for 1 100 000 000.

EDIT2:

Thanks for the hints. I am actually using the 2010 versions of the pages, I just posted the wrong link.
I did also follow the instructions on these sites and as I wrote, it works till I use more than 4 GB of RAM. 
I tried to run a 32 Bit app which uses more than 2 GB ram, didnt work of course.
Then I did the instructions on the page -> I was able to run that app with a usage of 4 GB.
Now, I wanted to allocate more than 4gb -> It didnt work.
Why I think it has to do something with the compiling thing is that you can set a certain flag which makes 32bit apps able to use 4gb, I thought that that is what the cross compiling option does. -> making it "somehow" compatible to 32 and 64 bit.

EDIT3: I do have 8gb installed on win7 64x

EDIT4: Sorry, for not commenting the single posts but if I click on "comment" nothing happens. 
But I just dicoverd something. the thing with the compiler is probably not the problem, as I can successfully allocated 2 vecs with one being of the size 500 000 000  and the other of 700 000 000. 
Has somebody else a clue why I can't allocated a vector bigger than 4gb?

Comment: Also ensure that you have the correct configuration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: and how much physical memory does your system have?

Comment: This question would be much easier to understand if you responded to answers by commenting on them, not by adding edits to your original question.  It's hard to tell who/what you're replying to.

Comment: We would need to see the code.

Comment: Your code is no doubt dying on an std::bad_alloc exception.  Individual allocations are still limited to 2GB on x64 in the msvc memory model.  Larger allocations are technically possible but would make array indexing very slow.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I didn't know that. Do you have some background info on that? I mean I can allocate a vec till 4gb.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not freezing but filling up your swap file.

If you run in debug mode, the runtime will fill the array with a special value (marking uninitialized variables). This might take a while!

---

I have no problems running this program in release mode

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>   v(2000000000);

    std::cout << v.size();

    return 0;
}
```

Runs in a couple of seconds (with heavy swap file activity) and prints the expected size.

Comment: The code you posted works for me too. It doesn't work if I build the array with push_back.

Answer (score 0):

*Now, my question is where I do have to put that extra "amd64"*

First off, you linked to the instructions for VS 2005, not 2010.  Although it probably doesn't matter in this case, there are a lot of differences between VS 2005 and 2010, so be careful and use the right documentation.  This is the correct [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

"amd64" is an argument you pass to vcvarsall.bat to initialize the environment for building x64 apps in a command line session.  It's not passed to your app, nor is it a project setting in the IDE.  The paragraph and table under "Vcvarsall.bat" in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) explains this.  The link Lirik posted in the comments explains how to configure your project correctly in the IDE, but again that's a link to VS 2005.  You want to use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Now, as for your bug, whether you're using the cross-compiler or native almost certainly has nothing to do with it.  That's a whole separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check is your application is 32 or 64 bits with the following command:

$ dumpbin /headers myprogram.exe

It should tell you the target architecture near the beginning.